# How can I reduce duplication on my automated tests?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, testcase

I am testing functionality where the user can add a country and update a country. However adding the country and updating the country is done on the same screen in the same fields.

For example I can go on edit country page and create a new country by adding name and coordinates or I can select existing country and update the name and coordinates. The problem I am having is that there is validation rules on the fields such as name has to be unique and certain amount of characters.

I don't want to repeat tests but it looks like I have to because when we add new country the backend rules will INSERT a new record and I have to check that the name is not duplicate e.g. country doesn't already exist. When we update country then the backend rules will UPDATE an existing record and I have to check that name doesn't already exist.

Pseudo code Test case 1:

```
//Go on edit country page to add new country
//enter a name which already exists 
//click save
//assert you get error message that country already exists
```

Pseudo code Test case 2:

```
//Select existing country this will open edit country page 
//update the name to another country which already exists 
//click save
//assert you get error message that country already exists
```

How can reduce the duplication in my code, I am doing everything in the Country test spec.

Comment: Tests are just code. Do what you'd do in normal code when you need shared functionality: write a function. Some test frameworks have their own way to make shared tests, like [RSpec shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/example-groups/shared-examples). To say more we'd need to know what test framework you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tests are still code. You'd solve it the same way you'd do with any code: write a function. Some test frameworks have special facilities like [RSpec shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-10/docs/example-groups/shared-examples).

You can also simplify the setup by sidestepping the UI and inserting data more directly.

Here's how I'd handle it with RSpec, [FactoryBot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot), and [Capybara](https://teamcapybara.github.io/capybara/) in Ruby and Rails.

```
context "when a country already exists" do
  shared_example "it shows a message about the duplicate country" do
    it 'shows a duplicate name error' do
      expect(page).to
        have_content("We already have a country called #{existing_country.name}")
    end
  end

  # We're not testing the UI can create countries, so make one using the model.
  # In this case via FactoryBot to fill in all the details we don't care about.
  let!(:existing_country) { create(:country) }

  context "when making a new country with the same name" do
    # This is all setup for the test, it's not what you're testing, so it's context.
    before do
      visit "/country/new"
      fill_in "name", with: existing_country.name
      click_button 'Save'
    end

    # Use the shared example.
    it_behaves_like "it shows a message about the duplicate country"

    # And test specific behavior. Again, we're not using the UI, we're using models.
    it 'does not save the new country' do
      expect(Country.where(name: existing_country.name).count).to eq 1
    end
  end

  context "when changing a country to have the same name" do
    let!(:country) { create(:country) }
    let!(:old_name) { country.name }

    # Again, we're not testing that the UI can edit. This is context.
    before do
      visit "/country/edit/#{country.id}"
      fill_in "name", with: existing_country.name
      click_button 'Save'
    end

    # Use the shared example.
    it_behaves_like "it shows a message about the duplicate country"

    # And test specific behavior. Again, using the models. Be sure to reload
    # any existing objects, if that's how your system works, after changing them
    # in the UI.
    it 'does not save the new name' do
      country.reload
      expect(country.name).to eq old_name
    end
  end
end
```

Your details will change, but the basic ideas will remain.

- Tests are just code. Break them up and share functionality similarly.
- Separate setting up the context from the actual tests and reuse the context.
- Avoid doing work via the UI unnecessarily. Testing the UI is complex and adds lots of code you're not testing.
- Have test factories to quickly set up test data.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how can I not use the UI? I have to enter text in the box then click the save button to get the message on the screen, this is UI testing im not testing the database.

Comment: @Junior It is using the UI, but only for the parts you're testing. `visit`, `fill_in`, and `click_button` are all Capybara functions which manipulate a browser to go to the edit page, enter text into the box, and click the save button. The test then checks if the expected message is on the resulting page. What *isn't* using the UI is the setup. We don't need to use the UI to add a country to serve as our duplicate to test against. Instead, we inject it directly into the database using a test factory; that's what `create(:country)` does above. This saves a lot of labor and its much faster.

Comment: @Junior Similarly, when testing that the edit did not change the name we check via the database, not the UI. We're not testing that the UI can display a country, we're checking that the underlying data was not changed by the UI. It's much simpler and faster. It's important to check both the displayed error message *and* that it did what it said it did.